# How to pass a date format from view in python to a <script> in html page

Tags: javascript, python, date

I set a field where the user can choose date range (Start, End):

```
if request.method == 'POST':
            fecha = (request.POST.get('datefilter')).split(' - ')
            start = datetime.strptime(
                fecha[0].strip(), "%Y-%m-%d").date()
            end = datetime.strptime(
                fecha[1].strip(), "%Y-%m-%d").date()
```

when I print the variable start after selecting the date range I get the correct date which was chose by the user. Now I have to take both of them (start and end) and send them to HTML page where I am going to use them but when I try to send them like this:

```
return render(request, "path/page.html", {"start": start, "end": end})
```

and get them like this inside the script in the HTML page

```
<script>

var start = {{start | safe}};              
        console.log(start);

var end = {{end | safe}};              
        console.log(end);

</script>
```

I am getting an integer instead of the date which I am trying to send from the view.

for example. If I want to call data from 25-01-17 to 25-01-18

25-01-17 would be the start date and 25-01-18 the end date so when I print those variables in the view to be shown in the console I get the correct date chose by the user.

```
print(start)
print(end)

output:

25-01-17
25-01-18
```

but when I try to print those same variables in the script inside html page, I get something different

```
console.log(start);
console.log(end);

output:

7
6
```

I realized that what is happening is a math operation. 25 - 01 = 24 - 17 = 7.

How can I solve this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Try just wrapping them in quotes, if they should be strings, like this:

```
<script>

var start = "{{start | safe}}";              
        console.log(start);

var end = "{{end | safe}}";              
        console.log(end);

</script>
```